# IllegalStateException when click on button in android hello world program

Tags: android

I'm new to android and I'm trying to implement MyFirstApp given on android google developers site, So app contains one textbox and button, if you enter any text in textfield and click on button it displays same content on screen, but having problem when i clicked on send button.
    Please guide me how to solve this problem.

Following exceptions:

```
<p>03-15 18:00:03.430: E/AndroidRuntime(592): FATAL EXCEPTION: main</p>
<p>03-15 18:00:03.430: E/AndroidRuntime(592): java.lang.IllegalStateException:Could not find a method MainActivity.sendMessage(View) in the activity class com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button</p>
<p>03-15 18:00:03.430: E/AndroidRuntime(592):   at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3031)</p>
<p>03-15 18:00:03.430: E/AndroidRuntime(592):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)</p>
```

Here are two activities:
 1.DisplayMessageActivity 
 this is activity mentioned in android manifest file . 
 This implement layout part

```
       public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        // Get the message from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        // Set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(textView);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message_1);

    }
       }
```

2.MainActivity
this is activity implement sendmessage function that is called when users clicked on    button .

```
      public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}
```

Android Manifest xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="11" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message">
           <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And Layout xml file:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" 
        android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: read the error. android is looking for 'MainActivity.sendMessage(View)', not 'MainActivity.sendMessage()'

Comment: @njzk2 actually I've edit code as one of the user is saying you should use sendMessage() as you are using sendMessage in xml. But anyway that was foolish answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

Change your Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="11" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message">
           <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>


<activity
            android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**DisplayMessgaeActivity**:

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        // Get the message from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        // Set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(textView);



    }
       }
```

**MainActivity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
  @Override
             protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message_1);
}

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage() {
        // Do something in response to button
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

---

your layout should have a life cycle method `onCreate`
It should have a onCreate method and you need to set
    `setContentview(R.layout.yourlayout)` for the MainActivity

Comment: I've tried that also but giving same exception, i think problem is different.from exception you can see-- could not find sendMessage method in DisplayMessageActivity, but method is defined in MainActivity.

Comment: @neel update your Question with new code that you have tried. And also logcat trace

Comment: updated, now you can try. It will be very helpful if you provide concrete solution.

Comment: @neel I have updated my answer check once, change your manifest with what I have posted, Your activities should register with manifest

Comment: @neel Have you tried? This is the concrete solution you are looking for.. And Don't forgot to accept this as answer by clicking the right mark beside the answer

Comment: yes I've tried. Thanks for superb solution to make my first app running.I think Google should correct his learning guide and mos probably they should have to make learning android easier for newcomers.Thanks.

Comment: @neel mark this as answer by clicking the right mark beside the answer

Comment: `button will look for sendMessage() with no parameters` absolutely not.

Comment: @njzk2 yeah I know, That was old answer, Before he actually edit his answer...And I already have edited my answer. Any how thanks for reply..I'll edit my answer, in case downvoters will hit and run..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your app is looking for the `sendMessage()` method in an activity where the method is not implimented

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException:Could not find a method MainActivity.sendMessage(View) in the activity class com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button</p>
<p>03-15 18:00:03.430: E/AndroidRuntime(592):
```

is this the xml layout name `activity_display_message_1` where you declare the Button?
you must put the method sendMessage also in the same activity

EDIT: FULL SOLUTION

activity_main.xml

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:onClick="sendMessage" />
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_display_message.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
    @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

DisplayMessageActivity.java

```
  public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message_1);


    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);
}
```

}

Update also you manifest file because you've inverse the launcher

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="11" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message">
           <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>


<activity
            android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: you are right, but i'm doing according to google site-http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: @neel in the google example there are 2 xml layouts one which contains the button which implements onclick listener and the second which should be call on click

Comment: @FestusTamakloe It has only one layout , for the second activity directly set the TextView brother

Answer (score 0):

You are using two time `setContentView()`. You can use only one `setContentView` .

Comment: should be a comment rather than an answer (mostly because it doesn't actually _answser_ the question)

Answer (score 0):

//Just change your manifest file, its not getting path of your "DisplayMessageActivity" for //sample as below :

```
 android:name="com.example.checkproject.DisplayMessageActivity"
```

or

```
android:name =".DisplayMessageActivity"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    this.startActivity(intent);
}
```