# Android button IllegalStateException with onClick(MainActivity)

Tags: android

Brand new to android. I have a button that is supposed to trigger an onClick method that is an override of the onClick method used with the onClickListener. The problem is that when I press the button an IllegalStateException is thrown saying that the onClick(MainActivity), as defined in the XML of the button, method cannot be found.

The code below is the code that throws the IllegalStateException. However if I change the XML of the button to android:onClick="onClick" then the button works completely fine. Why is this?

Button XML:

```
<Button
    android:text="Accept"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:onClick="onClick (MainActivity)" />
```

MainActivity Code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;



public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

private TextView textView;
private EditText username;
private EditText password;
private Button accept;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    accept = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
}

public void logIn(View view)
{
    Log.i("testUsername", username.getText().toString());
    Log.i("testPassword", password.getText().toString());
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
    if((Button)view == accept)
    {
        Log.i("testUsername", username.getText().toString());
        Log.i("testPassword", password.getText().toString());
    }
}


}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IllegalStateException when click on button in android hello world program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433064/illegalstateexception-when-click-on-button-in-android-hello-world-program)

Answer (score 2):

> Why is this?

Because `android:onClick="onClick"` is correct syntax. None of the following are correct syntax:

- `android:onClick="onClick (MainActivity)"`
- `android:onClick="onClick (View)"`
- `android:onClick="onClick(View)"`
- `android:onClick="onClick and anything else"`

Quoting [the documentation for `android:onClick`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:onClick):

> Name of the method in this View's context to invoke when the view is clicked. This name must correspond to a public method that takes exactly one parameter of type View. For instance, if you specify android:onClick="sayHello", you must declare a public void sayHello(View v) method of your context (typically, your Activity).

---

OK, with the help of @HappyRavi on Twitter, I was able to [reproduce the problem](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=225168#c2). It's an IDE bug that you will encounter if you do things in a certain order:

- Add the method that you want to route the click event to
- Drag the `Button` into the GUI editor
- Click the `onClick` drop-down in the Properties pane of the GUI editor

Doing things in a different order will not reproduce the problem.

With luck, they can get this fixed in some patch release for Android Studio 2.3.

Comment: Does Android Studio insert that - the `(MainActivity)` - automatically now, or something? This is not the first post I've seen about this, with the exact same wrong syntax.

Comment: @MikeM.: If it does, I am having difficulty reproducing it (testing AS 2.2.3). If you find a way to reproduce it, file an issue and, if you think of it, let me know.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe just a bunch of users following a bad example somewhere. Thanks for checkin'. And, yeah, will do.

Comment: The above code "onClick (MainActivity)" is what's generated automatically by Android Studio. I assume it's generated when the onClick override is created but I might be wrong. Either way that's what appears automatically and it's what I was instructed to use in the onClick field of the button by my university lecturer so I was just confused as to why it was creating errors when I was literally just following the instructions I was given.

Comment: @jm123456: Sorry, but I am not able to reproduce that behavior. I created a new project with the "Empty Activity" template. I deleted the `TextView` using the graphical layout editor and added a `Button`. I added a `public void foo(View v)` method to my activity. No `android:onClick` attribute was added to my layout. In the graphical layout editor, I typed in `foo` into the `onClick` field (since the drop-down did not give me `foo` as an option), and I wound up with `android:onClick="foo"` as expected. If you can give me steps to reproduce the problem, I would be happy to try them.

Comment: Try this instead. Create the button as you did. Implement View.OnClickListener into the class. Then right click and generate the onClick method override using the generate selection on the menu. That's what I did to create the onClick override. After this I went back into the design view of the app and in the properties menu of the button there was an option for "onClick(MainActivity)"

Comment: Just FYI, looks like it's been reported several times already. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=224494 http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=225168 http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=223537

Comment: @jm123456: "After this I went back into the design view of the app and in the properties menu of the button there was an option for "onClick(MainActivity)"" -- that part I am not seeing. When I click the "onClick" drop-down in the properties, I get no options, even after added `implements View.OnClickListener` and the corresponding method to `MainActivity`. What version of Android Studio are you running (see Help > About, or the title bar of the IDE window)?

Comment: @MikeM.: None have been accepted, which is bad. However, I'd like some confirmation that this happens on 2.2.3 (latest production build) before I try bringing more attention to the issue. All those issues cite 2.2.1 and 2.2.2 (or, in one case, "2.2").

Comment: @CommonsWare I apologise that I can't help further, but those are the steps that I took and I'm just telling you what I saw in my case. This is my first time using Android Studio so I'm not sure if anything else caused this to happen. I'm running version 2.2.3

Comment: @jm123456: It's an IDE bug -- see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

It should be implemented like below

```
<Button
android:text="Accept"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
android:id="@+id/button2"
android:onClick="buttonClickHandler" />//name of method should be given here
```

And add the method in Activity file

```
public void buttonClickHandler(View view) {
  //handle button click here
}
```

This will work only when method is added in `Activity` class and not with `Fragment`